# I did not get my Stack Overflow stickers

Tags: support

Now, you may accuse me of silliness or being childlike.

*But nonetheless*, I love stickers.

And in the spirit of sticker-love, I decided to follow the directions as per this highly-upvoted post: [May we have some more SO stickers, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200409/may-we-have-some-more-so-stickers-please)

I found an envelope, and then *another* envelope! I scoured my slovenly apartment for stamps. Upon finding stamps, I proceeded to google yet-again how to mail a SASE.

About an hour later, I happily walked to the mailbox. And mailed it off.

*And have been waiting more than 2 months! NADA*

Now, I understand quite well that Stack Overflow is not called StickerOverflow.

Granted, but still - the pang of unrequited love hurts. I did what you asked me to do. I sent a SASE. I got no stickers.

Am I being a stickler about this?

Happy upcoming-rest-of-week Stack

**EDIT**: It must be said - the stickers have arrived, & have already adorned my laptop :-)  Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the offer - You are being silly and childlike.

Comment: The problem appears to be sticker underflow.

Comment: It seems to me this should be an issue where you email the team rather than posting it here. It's not a question related to the site itself.

Comment: @KenWhite Email would probably be a tad more expedient, but asking here is fine. I'll pass this on to someone who handles this sort of thing these days.

Comment: Particularly the "stickler" part was clever. Most entertaining complaint I've seen in a while.

Comment: *I found an envelope, No two envelopes.* This line grinds my gears.

Comment: [What is this I don't even ...](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=What+is+this+i+don%27t+even) :D

Comment: +1 [i cry evertim](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=like+this+if+you+cry+every+time)

Comment: You'll get them in [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/192504).

Comment: @James: He gave you a choice, silly **or** childlike. You'll have to choose, sorry.

Comment: No two envelopes... what?

Comment: @MSalters: Who said that it is an exclusive or? In that case the OP would have written: "Now, you may accuse me of _either_ silliness or being childlike." Be careful, SO might be visited by programmers :p

Comment: Oh god, the use of really bad puns!!

Comment: Stickers are cheap though, we can aways print our own

Comment: Wait what? There's stickers?

Comment: @Zizouz212 - Of course !!

Comment: How come I've never heard of this? I want stickers!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Am I being a stickler about this?

Ha! Nice one.

I checked with our office managers and I'm told that we process these in batches, so everyone will get their stickers. *Eventually*. :)

Comment: You mean we can just email you guys and ask for stickers? Nice!

Comment: @Seth If we don't respond in 2 months after you mail us a SASE.... yes. ;)

Comment: @Seth You may email us and ask for stickers all you like. It helps me to pretend that I'm useful, and that people like me. Whether or not I actually _send_ them is another matter, but feel free to drop in anytime!

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion [Mail, not email](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/). We don't mind handing out stickers (once folks here know what to do with the envelopes), but if my job becomes nothing but dispatching stickers in response to emails... well, that'd be unfortunate for all involved. Mostly me. And the people who wouldn't get their stickers.

Comment: Noted. I will send a mail Anna.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm also going to send a snail-mail out to the Stack HQ. Stickers on my macbook air ;-)

Comment: I want tons of it!

Comment: @AnnaLear I received T-Shirts, Sharpies, A USB Pendrive and of course stickers but none of them had SO's branding.. (I know I should be thankful for that and I'm!) but everything was SE's :( I'd love if they were of SO's branding! Can you look into it? I mailed Tim long back and he said he will at least get a shirt with **Stack Overflow** branding on it!

Comment: How do I send you a SASE if I don't live in the US? Do I need to get hold of some US stamps somehow (for the return envelope)? Or is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: @starsplusplus Check out [the blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/) - there's something in there about an international reply coupon? I'm not sure how it works myself.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently you can't get them in the UK, but the blog posts also mentions an option to send a $1 bill, which I might have left over from travel. The blog post is from 2009, though. How do I find out if $1 is still enough?

Comment: @starsplusplus No idea, sorry. Make it $2 (if you have it, $1 is fine if you don't) and include a note to blame me if that's wrong. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I sent in a request for stickers with envelopes around the time this post was made and haven't received them yet. Any idea when the next batch is?

Comment: @ZachSaucier - Hmm patience patience , they shall arrive ;-)

Comment: @AnnaLear can i still ask you for a sticker

Comment: @FastSnail Yep. Follow the instructions in the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/).

Comment: So they're actually a real thing? Oh My God!!!! You'll have an envelope from me tomorrow morning!!!!!