# Are Stack Overflow stickers still available?

Tags: support, swag

Has anyone sent in to get the Stack Overflow stickers in 2015? I have read around and noticed that [the most recent account of receiving the stickers was from late 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278229/i-did-not-get-my-stack-overflow-stickers), so I was just wondering whether they are still available. A first hand account from someone who has sent in and received them would be fantastic.

Is this question more suited for Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278237/1947286

Comment: Yes, I received mine about 3 months ago. They are processed in batches, so don't expect them immediately.  I actually sent 2 envelopes off to them and got back a nice bunch - I think 6 stickers total.  You can use a service to create the SASE for you too, but its a little more money

Comment: So I guess - *rest assured* - stickers shall arrive someday, not sure when. if you really badly have  need stickers and have ample cash try Zazzle

Comment: For the other newbies, here is the relevant blog post: [How to Get Stack Overflow Stickers](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/)

Comment: They're going to be receiving tons of mail now because of the Meta Effect.

Comment: Don't edit your actual question like this.  Just accept the answer that mentioned this.  Alternatively, post your own answer.  Don't update the question itself with the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Generally, no. The company no longer sends stickers and they have closed their office in NYC, so requests sent to the address in the other answer will no longer be received.

I had a backlog of stickers while I worked at SO and would send them out if people wrote in to the contact form requesting some but I don't believe there's any other way to get them from the company any longer.

Comment: Wow. All the best for the future. Good luck.

Comment: @yivi Thanks! Still trying to figure that out but I've really appreciated all of the support I've gotten from the community here.