# How to get SO stickers in 2016

Tags: discussion, swag

I have read several questions, topics about this. I see, that number of stickers are limited, but maybe is there an address where I can send my request? I have found this [article](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/), but I have read that some guys didn't get items. I am hungarian, so my location makes situation maybe more difficult.

Comment: You get a sticker when you reach a reputation of 100K....

Comment: This is from [2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212915/158100) but you might give it a try ...

Comment: @rene But they want to get stickers in 2016 ...

Comment: I got stickers when I got kinda-elected. That'd theoretically be possible to do  in the next few months, if everything aligns perfectly. Probably not the *easiest* method.

Comment: @undo "I want to become moderator because I need Stack Overflow stickers". Probably not the smartest line to use while running for moderator :)

Comment: @Laurel But it would be an honest platform ;)

Comment: People who want stickers want me to be moderator because I want stickers. They're tired of all the losers without the stickers. The stickers people love me. When I'm moderator, we'll have the best stickers. We'll have, we'll have all the stickers.

Comment: Another not-the-easiest method to get stickers is to find a security vulnerability on Stack Exchange and report it [here](http://stackexchange.com/about/security). I did so and I got stickers and a t-shirt.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Nicely done, (un?)fortunately people outside the US won't fully appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. :) I think that's not unfortunate.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Are the stickers yuge? **Or**, do the stickers just look yuge next to the model's hands? Also, since Mexico is paying for these stickers, are they hecho en mexico **or** are they made here?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'll tell you about the size of the stickers and the hands and where they're made. A lot of people have been asking if they're yuge and who's paying for them. And I've said. I've said we'll have the best stickers and we will. They'll be the best. And it wouldn't surprise me if these comments get deleted for being off-topic. I'm not saying deleting off-topic comments is rigged, but I think it's rigged.

Answer (score 22):

Per [a comment by Adam Lear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278229/i-did-not-get-my-stack-overflow-stickers#comment234869_278237) on another question

> Yep. Follow the instructions in the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/)

So as of Aug of last year they were still doing it. There's a lot of specific instructions for international people so I would read the blog

Comment: Now we just have to test it out and confirm that it truly is still being done :)...

Comment: @iRove Yes but don't forget to expect 6 to 8 weeks delay.

Comment: @TAsk I'm sure there will be [a delay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/337688), but the only way to be **absolutely sure** that this procedure is still being done is for the OP to test it out.  So I would expect a delay in getting this question accepted. :-)

Comment: I wrote last year a letter and I got some stickers :) btw I life in Germany.

Comment: @rekire What did you send in the envelope? USD or Euro? And do we have to send International Reply Coupon?

Comment: I put two one dollar notes in the envelope. I read somewhere that this would be fine.

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm that this is still being done as of a few months ago.

I had the same question a few months ago, as I wanted some cool Stack Overflow stickers to put on my laptop.

I followed the steps in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/). The stickers came in a few weeks later, and are now stuck comfortably to the front of my laptop!

Comment: I will give it a try in a few days to see if it is still feasible this way :p